# Why I can not see project files in Dev-C++?

Tags: dev-c++

When I create a project in Dev-C++ 5.9.2 save it and open it's *.dev file there is no file below it in the project tree but I can compile and run it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using 5.9.2 and even I create Empty Project there is unsaved file that after compilation ask you to save it.

1. So be sure you are looking into tree Project and no Classes or Debug.
2. If you are looking into Project there should be +
3. However if it runs with black window and you still don't see project files post a screenshot please